# iOS app submission taking too much time

Tags: ios

I've tried to submit iOS app, my app is validated correctly and when i click submit from Xcode organizer, it is taking too long and it is not stopping anywhere. My app size is 40mb. Any ideas of why it is happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19020906/339171 this may to some one else

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953161/xcode-stuck-at-your-application-is-being-uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the application loader, which is the much better option as you can monitor each and every activity in it. And much easy to use.

Comment: Ok when i use it is asking to choose a file. What kind of file to be  chosen-- .ipa file or .app file

Comment: First you need to create the app ditribution build using "iphone distribution profile for app store" after it find out the build in build folder of the project's root directory. Compress the build to .zip file. This zipped file will be then used by the application loader.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have (sorry to say) a crappy connection. Have you tried monitoring your connection with something like iStat Menus or slurm, iftop?

Comment: No applicative firewall like LittleSnitch?

Comment: if i'm using application loader, what kind of file should be chosen to  upload -- ipa file or any other.

Comment: Take a look at the other answer please.