# application loader stuck at the stage of "Authenticating with the iTunes Store"

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I was about to upload an app to iTunes connect,but the application loader has been stuck at the stage of "Authenticating with the iTunes Store" and pending for almost an hour.Network is fine and I have never seen this before.Has anybody encountered this kind of issue? what is the solution?thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a programming question, it is an App Store process management question. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are plausibly multiple reasons that could cause this, but the primary one appears to be simply non-responsiveness from iTunes Connect. In my view, many of the proposed solutions are things people tried while waiting, that appeared to work as they then re-tried to submit. The network/proxy issues are real, but that's still not a programming issue per se.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I had this problem when behind a firewall.

I got around it by editing:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/java/lib/net.properties
```

If you do not find `net.properties` in above mentioned path then try, as it is changed now.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/itms/java/lib/net.properties
```

Change the line:

```
# https.proxyPort=443
```

To:

```
https.proxyPort=80
```

This enables the application to use the HTTP port for HTTPS. Worked straight away after this.

Comment: How do you do this? I am getting a permissions issue when I try to change this line (logged in with an administrator account)

Comment: I had the same problem like Nick ?

Comment: Its work in xcode before, i also tried this when i stuck in xcode 5.0.1 but its not uploading app when you do this in xcode 5.0.1, so i think its not now working but any how its working good before.

Comment: I left it `authenticating` but just as I was about to kill it and save my changes to the port that it uses, it's got beyond that step and uploaded the package successfully. In my case, it just required patience!

Comment: I couldn't find itms folder under MacOS. Anyone knows how to modify the file in Mac OS 10.9?

Comment: For all peeps who faced the permission - please login as root(admin) to do this.

Comment: Seems like the path has changed to:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/java/lib/net.properties

Comment: I have just copied the net.properties wiht ports changing to all 80 , but ti fails

Comment: Finally after trying tons of stuff I was able to resolve this issue as mentioned.

Uncommented the line "# https.proxyPort=443" and changing it to https.proxyPort=80. I was able to locate that file by manually going to that path instead of Finder "Go to" box which was complaining for path not found. I opened that file in Atom editor and edited it and saved it, it did ask Admin credentials though.

Comment: I wonder it is 2016 and why do we have such kind of issues still with Xcode with no prompt message regarding what the exact issue is.

Comment: To find the path for the file, use `find /Applications/Xcode.app/ -name net.properties`. Then `cd` to the folder with quotes (because of the space), and patch using `sudo sed -i.bak 's_# https.proxyPort=443_https.proxyPort=80_' net.properties`

Answer (score 38):

To be honest, this may not be an answer but it really worked for me.

1. I launched `Application Loader` and started submitting.
   While sumbitting was going on,
2. I launched `Organiser` and select `Distribution over archiver in Xcode`
   as well and started uploading concurrent.

They worked together and 2nd one completed the submission.

Just my experience.

Comment: This worked for me too after nothing else did and over a month of trying, so thanks a LOT bud :D

Comment: As a developer myself, I'm ashamed of trying a solution of this kind...  It's really weird. BUT this one worked for me too :D LOL!

Comment: I still don't believe it, but after almost a WEEK of unsuccesfull submission, starting both transfer actually worked at the very first try!!!

Comment: This worked for me too. After a week of unsuccessful submissions it worked for me just when i gave up the hope !!! Thanks bud :)

Comment: Hahahaha, unbelievable, I actually tried this as a last resort and it actually works... wtf!?! Java issues maybe!

Comment: holy crap. this worked after days of attempts. thanks.

Comment: Running two `Application Loader`s works as well, just tried it.

Comment: great answer.. you make my day

Answer (score 13):

I tried many solutions like using port 80 for https connection but none of the solution worked for me.

## https.proxyPort=443

to
https.proxyPort=80

Whenever I face this issue, I upload application from [two different instances](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.5.1.dmg) of application loader and it works like a charm.

I have two different versions of application loader on my machine, one came with XCode4 and one came with XCode5. It always works if I upload application from two instances simultaneously.

[image]

Comment: can you share the link to previous version ?

Comment: Well! even this is not a solution. I have tried multiple instances. nothing is taking me to upload stage.

Comment: Same solution in different way: Duplicate your Application Loader.app in /Applications or any other place and run both Application loaders at the same time.

Answer (score 9):

I was quite frustrated by this - not only by the problem itself but the uncertainty till when I need to wait to call it "It won't - try again." - at which point I will quit the Application Loader app, re-package my ipa file and try again. Probably with a port change to net.properties file. But it didn't always work the same way as it did last time. So I am writing it here, mostly for the sake of myself!

I was about to just call another day thrown when this worked, almost like a charm:

1) Open file. Applications > Xcode > Contents > Applications > Application Loader > Contents > MacOS > itms > java > lib - net.properties

2) Change the line:

```
# https.proxyPort=<whatever>
```

to

```
 https.proxyPort=80
```

Make sure that you do not uncomment `# https.proxyHost=` - just leave it as shown (commented).

3) Start Application Loader. Follow usual steps and start uploading your ipa using Send command.

4) If it seems to be getting past "“Authenticating with the iTunes Store” in reasonable time (say 10 minutes at which time my patience ran out) - you are lucky. Go sleep or hang out.

5) Launch Xcode Organizer. Select your archive and click Distribute button. It will show *slanting* progress lines for couple of minutes. If it doesn't stop, kill Xcode and retry.

6) After about 2 *slant* minutes, the blue solid progress will appear, and there flies your "Flappy Bird"...! (mine was neither Flappy nor Bird)

(Keep the Application Loader alive, just for the sake of having it around, I don't know if it's useful anymore, but I am just superstitious)

- Workarounds apart, this is something Apple must fix before releasing iOS 8 or iPhone 6. Seriously. If they don't, I am not wasting my $100 next year.

(Or - will this bug be still around to prevent those "Flappy" clones from flooding the app store, forever?)

Comment: This also improved my experience, from a Xamarin Studio iOS build of software. It's an unbelievable issue. Probably Apple is assuming that we all have 100 MB/s connections to the Internet, and is timing out your connection.

Comment: Seems like the path has changed to: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/java/lib/net.properties`

Answer (score 8):

Tested with xCode 5:
In my case nor organizer or application loader worked: they got stacked in “Authenticating with the iTunes Store”.

I solved it sending the app by application Loader, and when it got to the “Authenticating with the iTunes Store” I opened the organizer and upload the app: application Loader and organizer sending the app at the same time.

It seems that something is going in my router port configuration and my computer can not receive the answer from itunes store saying that authentication was successful. Maybe the process is this way:

1- Application loader request authentication.

2- Itunes store authentication is done but application loader never receives the answer. [But it is authenticated anyway!]

3- Organizer sends the app because it is already authenticated by application loader.

Comment: Worked for me. Nice :)

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem by starting second instance of Application Loader while first instance saying "Authenticating with the App Store...". You can start second instance of Application Loader from Terminal using:

```
open -n -a "Application Loader"
```

Answer (score 5):

Try use another internet connection. I have the same problem when try upload app via Wi-Fi. Nothing helps me, but when I disable Wi-Fi and try do it via EDGE on my iPhone, everything is works!

Comment: Probably the httpProxy workaround fixes the issue on SOME weird WiFi situations, but not the one in my case...

Answer (score 3):

You may give a try to `application uploader`. Yesterday me too faced this problem and even application upload didn't work for me then I tried this:

For uploading it via XCode:

> Step1: Firstly Validate your archive file by clicking on validation
>   button of Organiser.
>
> Step2: Then Upload it to App Store via Oraganiser. By clicking on
>   distribute and then first option and so on.

it really worked for me

Comment: OOPS,I did actually try your way first(with organizer),found it didn't work for me,so I turned to application loader.

Answer (score 3):

If validation is successful while uploading through organiser then it must be network issue. Application loader uses some specific ports including port 443. If any of those ports are blocked by your internet service provider or on your local network then application loader can stuck. Certain applications also block these ports. If you are running Skype close it. If it does not work then this solution worked for me finally. Make modifications in net.properties file. You can access this file by going to Application folder via terminal.Then move into Xcode.app with cd Xcode.app next

Contents with cd Contents next

Application Loader.app with cd Application\ Loader.app next

Contents/MaxOS/itms/java/lib

Now you find net.properties.

Now write sudo pico net.properties and add following lines in the file

https.ProxyHost=

https.ProxyPort=

https.ProxyUser=

https.ProxyPassword=

Now launch application loader to upload you ipa file and it will work like a charm.

Comment: Closing Skype immediately fixed the problem for me!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is the network trick. Connecting to different network may solve this problem.

I tried both the two ways(Xcode/application uploader) at home, neither worked.

Then, I brought my macbook from home to library, it finished uploading within 3~5 minutes there(via application uploader).

Answer (score 1):

Contents/MaxOS/itms/java/lib

Now you find net.properties. Edit that with your favourite text editor. Add the below lines

https.ProxyHost=

https.ProxyPort=

https.ProxyUser=

https.ProxyPassword=

You may have problem uploading through app store via xcode if you have slow internet connection, but using Application loader you can achieve the submission.

Comment: How do you fill value for those keys or just let them blank or use default value??

Answer (score 1):

We tried lot of things which is giving in this and other posts, but it did not work.

Finally we gave the IPA file to the client to upload it via Application Loader from his end. And it worked.

**So, I would strongly suggest that if your app validates fine and it still remains struck in Authentication, then rather than trying out anything, just try uploading it from totally different network in different geography.**

That will save you lot of time and headaches.

Answer (score 1):

[image]All i did was duplicate my Application Loader.app in /Applications and ran both Application loaders at the same time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple use this command in terminal it worked for me:

```
1. cd 
2. ~mv .itmstransporter/.old_itmstransporter/
3. "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue today while uploading .ipa via application loader which was opened directly from spotlight. Every time it was passing all the steps but getting stuck at Authentication. (AL Version 2.9)

After dozens of failed trials, I launched Xcode and opened application loader from Xcode (AL Version 2.8) and repeated earlier step. Interestingly it failed at first checking step itself! It said it had some issue with certificate .. so followed all the steps again to get new certificates in itunesconnect and on mac.
(if some one wants.. [here are good instructions with pics](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution_overview/publishing_to_the_app_store/))

It got authenticated and the binary file uploaded fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things including the suggestion provided here. Once I re-login in "Application Loader" to restart the delivery. The package passed the authentication stage and start uploading. Maybe "Application Loader" needs to revalidate your authentication but can't say it loud.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today. I shutdown my Mac and then tried the application loader after couple of hours.

It worked.

I guess it was a problem at iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Trying all these answers may work sometimes, but usually it takes much time and may not work at the end like in my case.

I figured out a solution which will probably work for all.

- Create your .ipa file by: Product -> Arcive -> Disribute(Save for Enterprise or ...) -> Next and save .ipa at target
- Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader -> Deliver your app -> Pick your .ipa file

Withing few minutes your app will submit to iTunes. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

- Charles Proxy (or any other proxy) could have this effect.
- Review and accept any new terms in member center.

Answer (score 0):

Best and quickest fix I found is to copy 'Application Loader' from 'Applications' folder to desktop, run both 'Application Loaders' simultaneously.

Works like charm every time :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with server of any ports in my case. I have 9 MB of build. With good interenet speed it takes 5 minutes. I feel I got stucked. But after few minutes it uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the distribution signing entity. I created and it did work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for days with this problem the only working solution for me is to use the Application Loader with only the DAV protocol selected.

Application Loader -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Use only DAV.

The problem is due to my corporate network restrictions.
DAV uses https so it's not blocked.

Solution found here:
[itunesconnect using application loader behind a firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069940/itunesconnect-using-application-loader-behind-a-firewall)

Answer (score 0):

open terminal and run these commands

- cd ~
- mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/
- "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application 
  Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter" 
  [got it from here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76803)

Answer (score -8):

**Hello Friends,** Do not worry about it, **Simply disable the bit code option in  build Settings and make build and upload.**

No need to do any extra work

**Try this one**

Comment: That's ok my friend, it was just your 100% working solution statement that made me respond. ;)

Comment: With this i was able to upload app on itunes

Comment: I understand, but what I'm saying is, you said "100 % working solution" based on 1 try, 1 success. So with my failed try, that's 2 tries, 1 success, 50% working solution. Right? ;)