# Cannot reach iTunes Connect after editing net.properties file

Tags: xcode5, app-store-connect

I was facing proxy issues when submitting my app to App Store. I followed [application loader stuck at the stage of "Authenticating with the iTunes Store"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971710/application-loader-stuck-at-the-stage-of-authenticating-with-the-itunes-store/19918707#19918707).

Now that I am done editing my net.properties file using text mate, I can not connect to iTunes Connect via Application Loader or through Xcode.

Comment: Did you try revert back changes and attempt to connect? The instruction you followed only let Application Loader to use port 80 (http) for https connection.