# Upload .ipa using application loader

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, ipa, application-loader

I want to submit iOS app using application loader. I keep seeing

> Authenticating with the iTunes Store.

On [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19997946/1798394) I found that I should change port from 443 to 80 in file

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/java/lib/net.properties.

But I am not able to do that.

Changing the file through terminal says it is read only. The answer in above link asks to use `text mate` command. But using that says `text -command not found`.

Is there a way to do it through finder? Or any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution from [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971710/application-loader-stuck-at-the-stage-of-authenticating-with-the-itunes-store/19360043#19360043).

Just restating from that :

> 1. Launch **Application Loader** and started submitting.
> 2. When it gets to the **Authenticating with the iTunes Store**,
> 3. Launch **Organiser** from Xcode and select **Distribution over archiver in Xcode** and start uploading .ipa file.

This will work. Look at more answers on same question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open file in textmate the run this commend

```
mate <the file name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Application loader must be compatible with xcode and itunes then only it will work, so please check for compatibility if the available application loader version is not compatible then you can download it from your developer account.