# Xcode Application Loader stuck at "Signing in to App Store Connect"

Tags: ios, xcode

*Note: this is NOT the same as being stuck at "Authenticating with the iTunes store" while uploading an app, which is well-documented on SO and elsewhere.*

When I first launch Application Loader, I'm prompted for a username and password.  I enter my credentials and click Sign In.  A message pops up saying "Signing in to App Store Connect" with a little spinner to the left.  Then a few seconds later, the spinner goes away, and I'm never brought to the page where I can upload an .ipa.  And I'm left questioning my life choices.

[image: Application Loader Sign In]

I have a coworker who experienced the exact same issue.  We each have email addresses associated to 2 Apple Developer accounts, we'll call them `nodice.com` and `allgood.com`.  We can both sign in to our `allgood.com` accounts fine.  But both of us experience this issue when signing in to our `nodice.com` accounts.

However, we can both sign in to both accounts at https://developer.apple.com/ and https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/.

The curious difference between the two, is that both of our `nodice.com` email addresses also belong to other organizations.  The `allgood.com` accounts have only been invited to one organization.  In other words, on the websites above, while logged in to the `nodice.com` account, I can switch between these organizations.  On the `allgood.com` account, I have only one organization to choose from.

[image: App Store Connect menu]

Even curiouser is this, which I found by accident: if I close the stuck login screen, I see the "Template Chooser" screen!  But the selected team is the one I don't want, and when I click the button, the menu is borked.

[image: Template Chooser]

Recently Apple made a change -- we all got the email -- that "Teams and roles have been unified" between the Apple Developer website and App Store Connect.  This could be related.

We are using Xcode Version 10.1 (10B61) and Application Loader Version 3.7.2 (1138), which as far as I know are the most recent versions.

I have tried modifying the `net.properties` file as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971710/application-loader-stuck-at-the-stage-of-authenticating-with-the-itunes-store).

I have also tried updating the `iTMSTransporter` using the instructions found [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76803).

I may just have to file a bug report with Apple, but I'm curious if anyone else has had this issue and has maybe found a workaround.

Comment: “may just have to file a bug report with Apple” That, or just contacting them via email, would be a lot more appropriate and effective than posting to stack overflow.

Comment: Were you able to go through this? I'm experiencing the same. BTW are you guys using a VM with Mac OS? I'm using High Sierra on Virtualbox.

Comment: Any update ? I am getting same issue.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with an account that has access to multiple teams. I used another account that only has access to the team I wanted to upload an app for and it connected instantly.

Did you file a radar that we can dupe?

Comment: I contacted Apple Support the day after I wrote this up.  The issue is not yet resolved on our end.  @LucianoFantuzzi we do use VirtualBox, but for a Windows guest on a Mac host.  The VM is not involved in our case.

Comment: @saeros I did not file a radar but please feel free to do so and add your link here.  Glad to know my company is not the only ones having this issue.

Comment: @Jesse Radar filed, you can dupe it from here https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4981261416267776

Comment: @saeros same for me, my account has multiple teams. It mysteriously solved itself the next day. The team in conflict was one of those I have dev only access. I think it might be related to some missing signature/user approval in one of those contracts they are every time updating, in the account of that particular team. Make sure all teams in your account are up to date with those contracts.

Comment: @Jesse You can also upload build from organizer.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this issue recently.. and I seem to have found a work-around. Inside of the `Application Loader.app` package there's a tool called `iTMSTransporter`. You can invoke it from the command line to upload your package!

```
$ /Applications/Xcode10.1.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter -m upload  -assetFile /path/to/YourApp.ipa  -u <email@address.com> -p <password>
```

This is it in use in it's simplest form: for more options you can run `iTMSTransporter --help upload`

Comment: Thanks, we'll give that a try!

Answer (score 0):

My answer may sound weird, I was stuck with the same issue for couple of days. Randomly on an assumption tried a scenario and that worked!

Funny thing is, ***my Email ID was registered under two organisational apple accounts (Developer program and Enterprise program)***.

- I removed myself from Enterprise account and got to successfully login to see the "Choose your app" screen.

Note: There was no issue before Apple's user roles merging activity.

Opened a bug with Apple, hoping to get this addressed soon.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled 2FA for your account? If not enabled, Xcode won't allow adding the account.

Answer (score 0):

Apple engineers have updated their servers and the app is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Application loader on xcode 10.2.1 still isn't letting me login with my apple ID