# Xcode stuck at “Your application is being uploaded”

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

I am facing an issue while submitting my app from Xcode to the App Store. I have done everything regarding my project, and its running fine on my iPhone and iPad. But when I submit my project I am facing a huge problem.

First after archive I have done the validate. Now my archive file in Organizer is showing status pass validation as well. So I believe I am at the final step of submitting the app.

1. I have clicked on distribute and selected submit app to app store.
2. After login I have selected provisioning files as well.
3. I am stuck here. You can see in the screenshot below. And I have never seen any
   progress bar where I can see the submission progress or something like that.

Only screen I can see is:

[image]

**Edited:**

It was near about 1.30 hours. And internet connection is working. My ipa file is only 3.5 MB.

And last when I tried Application loader to upload the same I received the following screen as well for a long time in **Authenticating with the iTunes Store...** ..

[image]

What should I do now?

Comment: Did you remember to click that additional "ready to upload binary" button in iTunes Connect?

Comment: Yes, I have done that @rokjarc

Comment: How long is it "stuck" on that screen? How fast is your internet connection and how big is your application?

Comment: Its near about 1.30 hours. And internet connection is going fine. My ipa file is only 3.5 MB @sbarow

Comment: This shouldn't be needed but maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19918707/653513

Comment: That's done the trick Thanks a lot man. Now in iTunes connect its showing me the status: Waiting For Review. Slidely offtopic but can you tell me how many time will take it to review my apps? @rokjarc

Comment: Hey, glad it helped. I've uploaded 4 apps in the last month. One was initial upload and took 8 days, others were updates and took from 3 to 5 days.

Comment: Thanks for your time. You are my hero. @rokjarc

Comment: Nothing worked for me, except joining the open network did the trick

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. There is no such path(```/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Content...```) available in my mac. Please help me out for the same. @Avijit  @rokjarc

Answer (score 83, accepted):

As I felt a serious issue on this. I believe this answer might be helpful.

After trying for around 10 to 12 hours to fix this issue and as everything else regarding my project and coding was fine enough, it became a headache for me. But after getting some valuable comments from some of the expert users of stack-overflow and after doing some more search on the internet, I have found some quality answers.

This answer helped me the most:

[application loader stuck at the stage of "Authenticating with the iTunes Store"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971710/application-loader-stuck-at-the-stage-of-authenticating-with-the-itunes-store/19918707#19918707)

*If you are going to upload it through Application Loader and it gets stuck on "Authentication with the iTunes Store..."*

or

*You are going to upload it through XCode and  it stucks on “Your application is being uploaded”*

**Then just keep your head cool and check this first method:**

- **Check if your firewall protection is off.** If not then turn it off. It maybe blocking you to connect your computer with iTunes
  Store.
- **Try a different internet connection.** The purpose for trying a different internet connection is that your current internet connection maybe blocking a required port for connection to Apple servers.

**If the above steps doesn't help you then follow this second method:**

Xcode needs java runtime for uploading your apps to the App Store.

enter 'java -version' in the terminal, java version should be 1.6 .If not then download
latest compatible java only from apple download center:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US

**If this still doesn't help then follow this third method:**

This method enables the application loader to use the HTTP port instead of HTTPS.

- Go to
  Application Loader java folder :
  **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/java/lib**
- Open **net.properties** file using any text editor application like `text mate` or `sublime text`
- Change this particular line : `#https.proxyPort=443` proxy port to
  `https.proxyPort=80`
- Save the file. And that's it !! You can easily upload your binary file to App
  store now.

**If the above methods still doesn't help then follow this fourth method: Regenerate your certificate**

- Goto iOS developer portal (https://developer.apple.com/membercenter).
- Revoke current certificate which is used by your App for signing.
- Remove current "iOS distribution provision profile" from Developer
  portal.
- Regenerate the iOS distribution certificate and add them in developer portal.
- Regenerate "iOS distribution provision profile" for app store
  distribution and download to mac.
- Install it.
- Try again using xcode/application loader to upload the build.

Comment: Great explanation pal :) more elaborative for answer method 1 approach.

Comment: Note that you need to delete the pound (#) sign. That sign is for comments and if it's there Application Loader will not see you want to use port 80 instead.

Comment: Guys I want to ask one question.For updated version I need to change Build and Version from 1.0 to 1.1 in Targets->Summary.

Comment: so what's the issue? @wimcNilesh

Comment: @wimcNilesh You only have to change **Bundle Version** field in your **Info.plist**

Comment: Thanks Avijit for your quick reply.In Info.plist Bundle version is changed to 1.1,but then also it's taking more than 1 hours to upload and it is continuing.

Comment: have you made all the changes I describe in my answer? @wimcNilesh

Comment: yes i tried through both xcode organizer and application loader

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44206/discussion-between-avijit-and-wimcnilesh)

Comment: Hey Avijit ,I got the result.Actually It was because of bad internet connection.Thanks for you help.

Comment: @Avijit hello, i am trying to follow your leading, and i have a question, if I remove the current certificate and provisioning profile, does it affect to the application which is now in app store? in fact I am afraid to delete them.

Comment: @Fatima come here for discussion http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45803/mobileappfactoryios-android

Comment: Can you add 'Henry_821018' approach too - reinstalling iTMSTransporter. That is the only way I managed to fix it. And, yours if the accepted answer so I didn't find his approach for *ages* :).

Comment: it seems like the path has been changed to : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/java/lib/net.properties

Answer (score 25):

There is definitely a problem if your app stuck on "application stuck process". I suggest you to go with Application loader rather than Xcode itself as Application loader shows the activity status. You can clearly know in which step you stuck.

The most frequent issue faced is to stuck on the "Authentication with the iTunes Store..." step.

There are possible two work around which I followed and finally submitted my app to app store. You can try both. For me both worked at least once.

**Method One : This method plays with proxy port to use http connection over https**

1. Go to Application Loader java folder : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/MacOS/itms/java/lib
2. Open net.properties file with "sublime text" or "text mate"
3. Change "#https.proxyPort=443" proxy port to "https.proxyPort=80"
4. Save the file and reopen Application Loader and Try again.

**Method Two : Regenerate your certificate and iOS distribution provision profile and Try to upload**

1. Goto https://developer.apple.com/membercenter
2. Delete previous certificate referenced by your App for signing.
3. Revoke your distribution certificate and download it to your mac. And install it by double clicking it.
4. Delete current "iOS distribution provision profile" from Developer portal.
5. Regenerate "iOS distribution provision profile" for app store distribution and download to mac.
6. Install it by double clicking it.
7. Try again using application loader to upload the build.

Edit: I again got this problem while uploading new build. Both of above methods were followed but was stucking in "Authentication..". Restarted the mac book and it worked. **When you restart, the previous itunesconnect connection (which you might have opened in browser prior to submit your app) are reset which allows restarted mac to easily authenticate iTunes Connect. Yesterday (jan 26, 2014) the iTunesConnect authentication step proceeded within 2 mins. Hope this helps someone who is loosing patience while stuck on authentication step.**

Edit 2: Before deleting distribution Certificate, try only regenerating "iOS Distribution Provision Profile". It worked for me else you can redo as above.

I Hope this helps. All the best.

Comment: I have already solved this by using First method. Anyway thanks for you answer.

Comment: @Andru: you can select mysticboy59's answer as correct so this topic will be closed. He did put some effort into it.

Comment: Actually there are some of the things too to done that. For that I have given an answer so that it can help later follower. @rokjarc

Comment: Ok, sure. At first this question was close to being a duplicate and now it's full of useful information.

Comment: Solution 1 worked for me, YOU SAVED MY PROJECT as tomorrow the will be the iTunes connect store shutdown and I had to deliver the game by today :).. SUPER THANKS!

Comment: Was stuck at "Authenticating with iTunes Store" with Xcode 7.1.1 and fixed it by simply restarting Xcode.

Answer (score 19):

I tried all the steps from Rajan's solution; none worked. However, this threads on apple dev forum (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76803) gave me the solution in my case :

*Try this, it fixed it for me. Open Terminal and run:*

```
cd ~  
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/  
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"
```

*iTMSTransporter will then update itself, then you can try uploading in XCode again.*

Comment: Solved for me too only after restarting os. Until that has been saying update was corrupted.

Comment: This worked for me, with resetting my developer certificate.

Comment: That took quite a while, but worked for me! No need to reset certs/dev profiles.

Answer (score 10):

For me, just logging out from ituneconnect website and developer.apple.com does work.And just using xcode to upload. No need to restart

Answer (score 6):

I got this issue today. But finally I found it's caused by my wrong settings.

In 'Build settings' of the target, change settings "**Code Signing Identity** -> Release" to your production certificate, and "**Provisioning Profile** -> Release" to your distribution provisioning file.

Then archive and distribute it again.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to cancel the upload and retry. If that does not work you may want to try the Application Loader from Apple. It essentially does the same thing, but does not resign the binary. You can download the application loader from itunes connect. See https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf (Getting Started, Page 9)

Comment: +1, uploading relaunch helped me in such situations.

Comment: I have tried that as well. Here also I am stucking in this position for last 15 minutes Authenticating with the iTunes Store...

Comment: Did you try to upload again with xcode or did you try the application loader?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

I cancelled and ran a validation check. It turned out I had written a `URL Scheme` incorrectly.

Xcode did not gave any errors when uploading and simply got stuck but validating gave the error.

So, try validation first. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

try this on terminal

```
cd ~  
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/  
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"
```

worked for me after hours of researching

Answer (score 2):

This is Happened Due to the iTMSTransporter
Try this, it fixed it for me. Open Terminal and run:
Use these commands one by one on the terminal. Hope it will help you

1. `cd ~`
2. `mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/`
3. `"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"`

iTMSTransporter will then update itself, then you can try uploading in XCode again.

Answer (score 1):

I met this issues many times, I tried all steps but it still not working (home network) and try other network work fine (company network).
I fixed this problem by update latest Java SE from 1.6 to 1.7 and it work like a charm

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, this may not be an answer but it really worked for me.

I launched Application Loader and started submitting. While sumbitting was going on,
I launched Organiser and select Distribution over archiver in Xcode as well and started uploading concurrent.
They worked together and 2nd one completed the submission.

Just my experience.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that I've changed my Dev. Account at some point of time and Application Loader itself was not authorized anymore. You have to manually to go it (Xcode -> Open Developer Tools -> Application Loader) and fill in your account details

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I as able to fix it by:

1. Remove/delete all distribution certificates and provisioning profiles from my machine.
2. Revoke distribution certificates and delete distribution provisioning profiles from Member Centre at developer.apple.com
3. Create a new Distribution certificated by generating a new certificate signing request from keychain access
4. Create a new provisioning profile for app store distribution
5. Download newly created certificate and add it to keychain access
6. Download newly created provisioning profile and add it to xcode. OR sync from Xcode from account settings.
7. Try to upload again.

This is some silly issue that Apple needs to fix asap. I wasted 2 days from something as silly as this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate. But it was not the issue. It is all the problem about the connection to the iTunes store from my mac machine(proxyPort).(see the accepted answer) Anyway It's now successfully released in app store.

Comment: Well, it's a case of same symptoms but different underlying problems. I didn't have any firewall or network issue, but the issue was related to regenerating certificate and provisioning profile, although it was already valid. I wish App Uploader had a more "verbose mode" which would display the exact state rather than a common message for some of the processes.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Logout from iTunes portal in all the browsers.
2. Restart your Mac machine.
3. Open Application Loader
4. Click on your Apple Login in the Top Right corner of the Application Loader Window.
5. Clicking Next will succeed your authentication process.
6. Now, do your process as usual by clicking upon the "Deliver Your App" and following the procedure beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Trying all these answers may work sometimes, but usually it takes much time and may not work at the end like in my case.

I figured out a solution which will probably work for all.

- Create your .ipa file by: Product -> Arcive -> Disribute(Save for Enterprise or ...) -> Next and save .ipa at target
- Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader -> Deliver your app -> Pick your .ipa file

Withing few minutes your app will submit to iTunes. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

All i did was duplicate my Application Loader.app in /Applications and ran both Application loaders at the same time.[image]
[image]

Comment: How did you duplicate the application?

Comment: copy and paste :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after updating Xcode5 to Xcode6. After hours of craziness, the one and only thing that helped me was to delete my account in Xcode preferences and add my account again.

Last week I had the same issue after update to Xcode7, this helped me again...

Answer (score 0):

If you are running inside a virtual machine (e.g. VMWare or VirtualBox), try setting the network adapter mode from the default NAT to Bridged.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I forgot to change the **Bundle Identifier** in **info** settings for the target. Hope it help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while uploading iOS apps through application loader.Then once after i opened iTunes parallel all of the sudden uploading apps was faster.Not sure if iTunes has any dependency with application loader.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me and my upload was hanging for days without any error. (my build was generated using Expo). Here's what I did to make this work:

1. In the apple's guideline, it says one way to upload the build is to use the [Transporter](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12).
2. Using the Transporter, it was able to detect and output the error.
3. It turns out the root cause for me was the XCode version was 9 but it has to be 10.

I hope this helps others who are struggling on this issue.