# Stuck at application upload to appstore in mavericks

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I am stucked while uploading to app store, with the message "**Your application is being uploaded...**"

I have tried all the steps mentioned here:[Xcode stuck at “Your application is being uploaded”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953161/xcode-stuck-at-your-application-is-being-uploaded/22216320#22216320)

Things I did,

1. My firewall protection is off
2. Changed #https.proxyPort=443 proxy port to https.proxyPort=80 in net.properties.
3. Tried to upload from Application Loader but stucked at "Authenticating with the iTunes store..."
4. Deleted old certificate,and provisioning profiles, Got new ones.

None of them are working. My system configuration are as follows: OS : 10.9.2 Xcode :5.0 Java : I upgraded from jdk 6 to jdk 7

Jdk folders at Jdk Folders at /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines are -1.6.0.jdk and -jdk1.7.0_25.jdk ( I have tried with 1.6 alone and 1.7 alone also).

When I run java -version from terminal - java version 1.7.0_25

( I have also tried with version 1.6)

JRE version: From system preferences - > Java -1.7

I have tried to upload from two different places but still no luck.

Are there any other methods to solve this issue? Or is my system configurations, java version ,JRE etc wrong,should i update Xcode?

This is my first upload to app store after upgrading to mavericks/Xcode 5. Prior to this there was no problem. When I validated the app before distributing, it is validated without any problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens to me also many times, you can do Something like,

1. if upload from Application Loader Make sure you are login into itunesconnect in safari.
2. Uplaod it to some older Version of Application Loader
3. Upload from Different MAC may some of your friend or colleagues.

Comment: No luck, I am logged in itunesconnect in safari and also in app store , but still same problem. Also tried with Application Loader version 2.8 and 2.9 , separately and simultaneously.

Comment: Didn't work from another MAC either. Other MAC is similar in configuration to the first one.

Comment: Try with some other netwrok, some times it also happens.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I had already tried two networks. They didn't work. Just now I tried the third network. And it works. It is working from both Organizer and Application loader.