# Application is not uploading in app store

Tags: ios, app-store

I am trying to upload my application on app store from 2 days, but it does not. I successfully pass the  validation and when i upload, it stuck on "authenticating with the iTunes store".

Can anyone help me to overcome this problem?

Comment: That could be anything - double check all your certificates and provisioning/distro profiles...

Comment: This already has an answer here. plz check here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/19997946/3615320

Comment: I already check it, everything is correct

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode stuck at “Your application is being uploaded”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953161/xcode-stuck-at-your-application-is-being-uploaded)

Comment: Chan Thanks, but i already try all this things but it won't work

Comment: Some time ago I faced the same problem. In my case the Firewall was locking connections with the port used to connect with Apple.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I checked firewall is off

Comment: iTunes Connect was down for a while. Try it again now.

Answer (score 1):

http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/45493-application-loader-stuck-at-%E2%80%9Cauthenticating-with-the-itunes-store%E2%80%9D-when-uploading-an-ios-app/

Try this!!!!
All the best!!!!